# GWT RequestFactory examples?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Do you know where i can find some code examples for the new GWT 2.1 RequestFactory? Google's tutorial is not good enough to begin with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please check this

http://javaasylum.blogspot.com/2010/11/gwt-21-request-factory.html

and from googler :

https://wave.google.com/wave/?pli=1#restored:wave:googlewave.com!w%252BWU4iAICkI.1

Comment: Thank you, do you know where to put this code, maybe at entry point class?:
EmployeeRequestFactory factory = GWT.create(EmployeeRequestFactory.class);
factory.initialize(new SimpleEventBus());

Comment: You can easily see the client - server interaction in this sample. Please check it http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples%2Fexpenses%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fgwt%2Fsample%2Fexpenses%2Fclient%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: You need only two interfaces : RequestContext and EntityProxy

Comment: The Google Wave link is dead by now

Answer (score 3):

And written in 2011 there are these tutorials which use ServiceLocators and show how to split the server side code using DAOs.

http://cleancodematters.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/tutorial-gwt-request-factory-part-i/

http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/using-gwt-requestfactory-with-objectify/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the DynaTableRf sample from a GWT 2.1 distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Simple example for Gwt Request Factory...
 [code is here](http://code.google.com/p/lvhung/source/browse/trunk/mycontact/)

AND WORKING URL IS 
[here](http://lvhung.appspot.com)